# About auto starting programs on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, startup, application

We have 10-15 programs on working windows server machine.Desktop and console applications.These applications is critical and cant stop.Is there any tool or software,when application is crashed or closed etc,it will starts again my application.

Thx.

Comment: are these custom in house applications? Do they run as services?

Comment: Don't agree with the close vote .. this seems a clear "sysadmin" issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check this software that can automatically restart a crashed application.

http://www.jockersoft.com/english/appmonitor_index.php

Comment: if the appmonitor is not smart enough to know when a service is really down as in  the service is shown running but in reality its toast then these types of apps monitors aren't much better then the normal service restart functionalilty of the service managers, correct?